# Symfony2 - stylesheet changes not reflected

Tags: symfony

I am working on a web application and using Symfony2 for the first time.

I have this problem: I have a template which references a stylesheet. Now, when I make changes to the stylesheet (e.g. change font colours), they are not reflected on the page when I open the page in my browser. It keeps on using the values of the original stylesheet as though it was never changed (in fact, I even removed the stylesheet completely, still the page displays the values of the original stylesheet).

Here is the code in the template:

I have already tried clearing the cache and running Assetic:dump with no success. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

p.s. I am working in the dev environment

Answer (score 1):

By default, symfony will make an hard copy of your assets in the web directory. If you want to have your changes reflected automatically, you need to make a symlink instead of an hard copy.

You can use this command:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

Comment: note that you can't use --symlink if you are in windows enviroment